# how to return data from dynamically build form fields for insertmany

Tags: node.js, forms, mongodb, express, post

Im building a form in ejs based on files read from a sourcefolder. Each file will generate a number of fields in a form. The user can add metadata to each file and on submitting the entire form the data should be saved in mongodb. So how do I define the names in the fields so that I ideally could pass the entire req.body directly into mongodb like in this question: [Post Multiple JSON Objects Simultaneously with Express and Postman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35488386/post-multiple-json-objects-simultaneously-with-express-and-postman).
I have tried with parametrized names like name = "size_<%= data[i].invNr %> but then I have to do a lot of parsing in order to get back to the individual objects.

```
<form action = "/" method = "POST">
    <div class="form-group">
      <% for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) { %>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4"><a href="<%= data[i].fullPath %>"><img src="<%= data[i].fullPath %>" width="200" class="media-object"></a></div>

        <div class="col-md-8"><i class="fa fa-certificate"></i>

          <span>Original: <%= data[i].origFile %></span>
          <br>
          <span name="katnr">KatalogNr: <%= data[i].katNr %></span>
          <br>
          <span name="invnr">InventarNr: <%= data[i].invNr %></span>
          <br>
          <span>FullP: <%= data[i].fullPath %></span>
          <br>
          <span>Test: <%= data[i].test %></span>
          <br>
          <input type = "hidden" id="invnr_<%= data[i].invNr %>" name ="invnr" value="<%= data[i].invNr %>">
          <input type = "hidden" id="fullpath_<%= data[i].invNr %>" name ="fullpath" value="<%= data[i].fullPath %>">
          <span>Comment: <%= data[i].comment %></span>
          <br>
          <span>Color</span>
          <input type = "text" id="color_<%= data[i].invNr %>" name ="color" value="Viggo<%= data[i].invNr %>"> 
          <br>
          <span> Size</span>
          <input type = "text" id="size_<%= data[i].invNr %>" name = "size" value="Otto <%= data[i].invNr %>"  > 
        </div> 
      </div>
      <hr>
      <% } %>
      <input type = "submit" value = "Submit">
    </div>
  </form>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML**

```
 <form action = "/" method = "POST">
  <div class="form-group">
  <% for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) { %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4"><a href="<%= data[i].fullPath %>"><img src="<%= data[i].fullPath %>" width="200" class="media-object"></a></div>

    <div class="col-md-8"><i class="fa fa-certificate"></i>

      <span>Original: <%= data[i].origFile %></span>
      <br>
      <span name="katnr">KatalogNr: <%= data[i].katNr %></span>
      <br>
      <span name="invnr">InventarNr: <%= data[i].invNr %></span>
      <br>
      <span>FullP: <%= data[i].fullPath %></span>
      <br>
      <span>Test: <%= data[i].test %></span>
      <br>
      <input type = "hidden" id="invnr_<%= data[i].invNr %>" name ="invnr[]" value="<%= data[i].invNr %>">
      <input type = "hidden" id="fullpath_<%= data[i].invNr %>" name ="fullpath[]" value="<%= data[i].fullPath %>">
      <span>Comment: <%= data[i].comment %></span>
      <br>
      <span>Color</span>
      <input type = "text" id="color_<%= data[i].invNr %>" name ="color[]" value="Viggo<%= data[i].invNr %>"> 
      <br>
      <span> Size</span>
      <input type = "text" id="size_<%= data[i].invNr %>" name = "size[]" value="Otto <%= data[i].invNr %>"  > 
    </div> 
  </div>
  <hr>
  <% } %>
  <input type = "submit" value = "Submit">
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
var main = {}
for(var i = 0;i<req.body.invnr.length;i++){
 var obj ={
 invnr:req.body.invnr[i],
 fullpath:req.body.fullpath[i],
 fullpath:req.body.color[i],
 fullpath:req.body.size[i]
}
 main.push(obj);

}
console.log(JSON.stringify(main))
```

Comment: Thank you! That did it. Minor detail I had missed was to set app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));