# How to send multiple requests via Postman

Tags: json, post, postman

I know we can send a json object via Postman as a POST request. However, I wish to send multiple such json Objects(hundreds) consecutively via. Postman.

Is there some way I can achieve that? I am stuck and will highly appreciate some solutions.

TIA:)

Comment: Try this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35488386/post-multiple-json-objects-simultaneously-with-express-and-postman

Comment: Thanks for pointing that one. But i cannot modify the code that handles the post requests on the receiving end. So, I need a solution that sends individual json objects consecutively rather than sending it as an array

Comment: Try using Runner in postman. Try this https://timbeynart.com/2017/03/14/use-postman-to-hammer-a-rest-api/ on how to send consecutive requests

Comment: Didn't suit my use case. Thanks anyways:)

Answer (score 2):

So I ended up sending the json data via. a java code through POST requests.
Since I needed this only for load testing, I didn't care much about the code efficiency here. Might be useful for someone

```
String line;
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("data.txt"));
while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(line);
            HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
            try {
                HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://url");
                StringEntity params = new StringEntity(jsonObject.toString());
                request.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
                request.setEntity(params);
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);.
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                // handle exception here
            } finally {
                httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
            }
}
```