# How to pass two different objects to a POST request in postman to test RESTful API?

Tags: json, rest, spring-boot, postman

This is actually a two part question, one is, how to pass two JSON objects, anther one is how to create object from two different classand pass that object to a POST method.

I am trying to test a POST method of RESTful API by passing two different objects in postman. I could successfully test only a POST method with one object, but when I am trying to send two different object to POST method where two different objects  , postman say's bad request.

Here is my two entity class: First one is Cleint class:

```
import lombok.Data;
import org.zevgma.api.entities.user.User;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "client")
public class Client {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "user_pk_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "user_pk_generator", sequenceName = "users_user_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false,  columnDefinition = "serial")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String email;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Date userDateCreate;

 }
```

Second one is about ClientAddress:

```
import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Data
@Entity
public class ClientAddress {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private int streetID;
    private String streetName;
    private int streetNumber;
}
```

I have tried different POST request with JSON objets or JSON nested threads in Stackoverflow and youtube, but could not find my solution.
Spceially I have tried instructions from these threads:

- https://it.mathworks.com/help/thingspeak/bulkwritejsondata.html
- [Post Multiple JSON Objects Simultaneously with Express and Postman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35488386/post-multiple-json-objects-simultaneously-with-express-and-postman)

Here is the POST method of RESTful API which one I want to test:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/api/employees", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<String> createClient(@RequestBody Client client,
                                           @RequestBody ClientAddress clientAddress){
    clientService.save(client);
    clientAddressService.save(clientAddress);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(client.getName() + " and "+ clientAddress.getStreetName() + " successfully added",
            HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

So far I have tried with this JSON object:

```js
[
{
     "name": "Bilbo",
      "email": "bilbo@gmail.com"
    },
  
  {
     "streetName": "Central Street",
     "streetNumber": "31"
   }
]
```

```js
[
 {
  "client":{
               "name": "Bilbo",
                "email": "bilbo@gmail.com"
              },
  
  "clientAddress":{
                      "streetName": "Central Street",
                      "streetNumber": "31"
                     }
   }
]
```

By Pre-Request Script:

```js
 //Pre-request Script
 var client = {
     "name": "Bilbo",
     "email": "bilbo@mail.com"
 }

var address = {
    "streetName": "New Street",
    "streetNumber": "3"
}

pm.environment.set("client", JSON.stringify(client));
pm.environment.set("address", JSON.stringify(address));

//Body
[
{{client}},{{address}} 
]
```

Now the second part of questions: What if I want to create a new object, ClientData from the above two mentioned class, Client and ClientAddress and pass this ClientData object to a POST method, how to do it.

Here is the ClientData class:

import lombok.Data;

```
@Data
public class ClientData {

    private Client client;
    private ClientAddress address;
}
```

And here is the POST method where I want to pass a ClientData object:

```
  @PostMapping(value = "/api/employees", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<String> createClient(@RequestBody ClientData clientData){
               Client client = clientData.getClient();
                clientService.save(client);
            ClientAddress clientAddress = clientData.getAddress();
            clientAddressService.save(clientAddress);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(client.getName() + " and "+ clientAddress.getStreetName() + " successfully added",
                HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

To test method in postman I should create these complex ClientData JSON object and how to pass the it?

Answer (score 2):

Your ClientData class is

```
@Data
public class ClientData {

    private Client client;
    private ClientAddress address;
}
```

So you request payload should look like

```
    {
        "client":{
               "name": "Bilbo",
                "email": "bilbo@gmail.com"
              },

        "address":{
                      "streetName": "Central Street",
                      "streetNumber": "31"
                     }
      }
```

Notice address instead of clientAddress.
Also you don't need to pass it as array it will be just a json object (not [])

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing this in the body:

```
[{{client}}, {{address}}]
```

Replace it with this:

```
{{requestBody}}
```

Now, store the complete body in an environment variable.
Remove the separate variables for client and address and just use a single variable.

So, update your pre-request script to something like this:

```
pm.environment.set("requestBody", JSON.stringify([client, address]));
```

Comment: If this doesn't help, then open Postman Console (View > Postman Console), now send the request and share the screenshot of the RequestBody being sent out as the request.

Comment: unofrtunately didn't work. Please follow this link for the screenshots of the output: https://imgur.com/a/WejRrR6

Comment: Oh, so the request body is going correctly. There's an issue with the server code, maybe the other responses will help you out.